# Why a class that implements an interface is not recognized as implementing a parent interface?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface, delphi-7

I have to write some interfaces that will be used to implement a number of classes. Some of them will have a "basic" behaviour, others whill have some "advanced" features.
I think the best way is to declare a "basic" `interface` and an "advanced" child `interface`.
I'm also tryng to keep a loose coupling between objects and interfaces.

Now I'm running into this problem:
When I create an "Advanced" object (implementing the Child interface), I expect it also implements the Parent interface, but neither "getInterface" nor "Supports" seem to agree with me.

Here is a sample code:

```
type
  IParent = interface
    ['{684895A1-66A5-4E9F-A509-FCF739F3F227}']
    function ParentFunction: String;
  end;

  IChild = interface(IParent)
    ['{B785591A-E816-4D90-BA01-1FFF865D312A}']
    function ChildFunction: String;
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IChild)
  public
    function ParentFunction: String;
    function ChildFunction: String;
  end;

function TMyClass.ChildFunction: String;
begin
  Result := 'ChildFunction';
end;

function TMyClass.ParentFunction: String;
begin
  Result := 'ParentFunction';
end;

var
  Obj: TMyClass;
  ParentObj: IParent;
  ChildObj: IChild;
begin

  Obj := TMyClass.Create;
  ChildObj := Obj;
  WriteLn(Format('%s as IChild: %s', [Obj.ClassName, ChildObj.ChildFunction]));
  WriteLn(Format('%s as IChild: %s', [Obj.ClassName, ChildObj.ParentFunction]));

  if (Obj.GetInterface(IParent, ParentObj)) then
    WriteLn(Format('GetInterface: %s as IParent: %s', [Obj.ClassName, ParentObj.ParentFunction]))
  else
    WriteLn(Format('GetInterface: %s DOES NOT implement IParent', [Obj.ClassName])); // <-- Why?

  ParentObj := ChildObj;
  WriteLn(Format('%s as IParent: %s', [Obj.ClassName, ParentObj.ParentFunction]));

  if (Supports(Obj, IParent)) then
    WriteLn(Format('Supports: %s Supports IParent', [Obj.ClassName]))
  else
    WriteLn(Format('Supports: %s DOES NOT Support IParent', [Obj.ClassName]));   // <-- Why?

end.
```

and here is the result:

```
TMyClass as IChild: ChildFunction
TMyClass as IChild: ParentFunction
GetInterface: TMyClass DOES NOT implement IParent
TMyClass as IParent: ParentFunction
Supports: TMyClass DOES NOT Support IParent
```

How can I, for example, test if an object implements `IParent` OR A DESCENDANT of it?

Thank you

Comment: You **must** implement the interface if you want to support it, because each implementing class can implement the interface in a different way. Just have a look at http://pastebin.com/PkQidhFc

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `TMyClass` doesn't support `IParent` is because you didn't say it should do so. That is just as designed. If you want `TMyClass` to support `IParent`, just say so in the declaration:

```
TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IParent, IChild)
```

Comment: I got it, but I'm missing the point of `IChild` deriving from `IParent`, then.